# Any tutorial to create new product type in Magento with custom attributes?

Tags: magento, product

We have an requirement to create custom product type in magento with custom attributes but not getting any good references for this??

Some of the references we followed:-

1.)http://blog.paulclegg.me/post/4183393562/magento-how-to-create-a-custom-product-type-the-bare

2.)http://blog.magestore.com/2014/02/03/add-custom-magento-product-type-magento-tutorial/

But it's not working at all.

Any references for same??

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following URL:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-a-new-product-type-in-magento/

They have created a module to create a new product type in Magento.

Comment: Yeah,I have gone through this but this is more a module rather than tutorial explaining steps by steps..Anyway thanks for suggesting!!!

Comment: Use this updated link http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/creating-a-custom-product-type-in-magento/